# MVC - Returning File Attributes in CSHTML from Azure httppost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have an issue where I am unable to return the Filename and File Size of files which are being uploaded to a website and stored on Azure, even although the variable names exist within the Controller.

A snippet of my CSHTML looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover ">  
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>FIlename</th>
    <th>Modified</th>
    <th>File Size</th>
    <th>Download File</th>
    <th>Delete File</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>@item.Name</td>
    <td>Modified</td>
    <td>@item.ContentLength</td>
    <td><a id="@item" href="@item" onclick="downloadFile('@item')">Download</a></td>
    <td><a id="@item" href="#" onclick="deleteFile('@item')">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, I have item.Name but I've tried many others which I'll summarise below all that I've tried. It's worth noting that I am able to download and delete the file perfectly fine.

My most important part of my Controller is:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    BlobStorageService _blobStorageService = new BlobStorageService();

    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = _blobStorageService.GetCloudBlobContainer();
        List<string> blobs = new List<string>();
        foreach (var blobItem in blobContainer.ListBlobs())
        {
            blobs.Add(blobItem.Uri.ToString());
        }
        return View(blobs);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = _blobStorageService.GetCloudBlobContainer();
            CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName);
            blob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Upload");
    }
```

As you can see, the ContentLength which is the file size and FileName exist within the HomeController context.

I have tried the following different examples in order to get it working

@item.FileName, @item.file.FileName, @item.HttpPostedFileBase.Filename
@file.FileName, @item.filename - and all the same for the others.

If you do know the answer, can you tell me the source of where you found it, I'm used to working with Python which have documentation of their modules but this is much different

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the ViewModel you use to render the GET Upload view.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Upload() {      
    List<string> blobs = new List<string>();
    // add URI strings to list ...
    return View(blobs, "Upload");
}
```

This means in your CSHTML, `Model` is a `List<string>`.

What you actually want is a collection of viewmodels that hold the FileName and ContentLength, not just the URIs.

```
public class FileDisplayModel {
    public string Uri { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ContentLength { get; set; }
}
```

Using an `@model` directive in the cshtml allows the IDE to check whether you are passing the right model from your controller.

```
@* Upload.cshtml *@
@model IList<FileDisplayModel>
```

Documentation for .net can be found on MSDN: [HttpPostedFileBase Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is a tutorial I used for image uploads: [File Uploads in ASP.NET MVC with View Models](http://cpratt.co/file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc-with-view-models/)

Comment: So I should create a new Model called FileDisplay?

Comment: Yes, create and fill a ViewModel in your Controller, then use it to render your View.